# R/python - Dynamic edition of excel workbook (formulas in cells)

Tags: python, r, excel, xlconnect

After days of searching on SO and elsewhere, I can't find a definitive answer. As I'm sure I'm not the first one to wonder about this, I hope one of you can enlighten me.

I have an xlsx workbook, with simple formulas in several cells (like SUM, ...).

Let's say:

```
A1 = 10
A2 = 20
A3 = A1+A2 (so basically A3=30 to start with)
```

I need to run a script that will, for instance, change the value of A1 (like a thousand times), and save the value of A3, for stat purposes. Ideally this needs to be done on a web server.

For now, I am using the **XLconnect** library in **R**, that allows me to import the xlsx file, edit some cells, and the formulas are automatically applied where they need to be (so if I change the value of A1 and then go read A3, the changes will be taken into account).

The only problem with XLconnect is that it is really slow, because of the Java dependency if I understood well. Writing a cell and reading another one takes excessive amount of time, so doing it thousands of time might be painful. 
For example, 10 iteration on a "normal" workbook takes around 10 seconds. I could parallelise the computation, but I have read that parallelising when depending on a JVM is impossible.

I have tried other libraries and other languages (R/**openxlsx**, R/**xlsx**, R/**xlsReadWrite**, Python/**openpyxl**), and none of them seem to dynamically update the cells. When I update the value of A1, the reading of A3 will still be 30. Or maybe I am using them wrong.

**Hence my question:**
Is there a language/library that allows to import an excel file, while keeping the dependencies between cells, and that does not rely on Java? 
Or a way to speed-up the process (by, for instance, calling the JVM only once, and not each time I read/write a cell)?

Comment: Why do you need Excel? Why not just do the calculations in Python/R whatever?

Comment: Not needing Excel would be the dream. Unfortunately I need to run the script on Excel workbooks from different people. They already use Excel for all kind of useful purpose. I simply cannot ask them to format their data differently.

Comment: Do all calculations in R and/or Python, then output final results in formatted Excel workbook -only **once** at the end! Of course you could use Excel VBA which by default connects to the Excel object library (of course R and Python can connect to it via COM as well).

Comment: If you work under the Windows you can try `excel.link` (R package). It uses COM to access Excel data. There is also `xlwings` for Python with COM support.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @Parfait: that is the final solution that would require to modify deeply the excel file before sending a matrix n*1000 instead of 1000 times writing a vector of size n in a size n area in the excel workbook. Ideally I would like not to modify the excel file (or very minimally).

Comment: @Gregory: I thought xlwings was some kind of plugin for excel, I guess I was mistaken. I am not on Windows, but I can VM, so I'll definitely give a try to both.

Comment: @GregoryDemin: I've tried both your solutions, and as expected when you mentioned the COM support, Excel is required for the library to work. Is there a way to use the libraries without Excel installed? Or is there a way to make it a server-based app?

Comment: @jav As far as I know to use Excel via COM we need that Excel will run on the same machine with script. There is a project (https://sourceforge.net/p/excelsir/wiki/Home/)  which connects Excel with R on the remote server but as far as I understand it require special Excel plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a very good excel library

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

You could use jython to meld the two realms of java and python.

Comment: Thank you David for your answer. Unfortunately, from what I see, JXL does not support xlsx files. Since I cannot expect people to format their worksheet to be xls, the only way would be to personaly convert xlsx into xls, which I am not sure is (easily) possible.

Comment: Xlsx uses the open docs format which is xml, you can read xml in python easily with xmltodict